# Alert not showing value of td element's id on click.

Tags: javascript

I want to get the id of `td` element on it's click.

Javascript code is -

```
 $('#example').on('click', '.alertShow', function () {
            var id=$(this).closest('td').attr("Id");
            alert(id);
    }
```

And this is HTML

```
   <table border="1"  id="example">
    <tr>
    <td class="alertShow" id="2_0">
    </td><td class="alertShow" id="2_1">
    </td><td class="alertShow" id="2_2"></td>
    <td class="alertShow" id="2_3"></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="alertShow" id="3_0">
    </td><td class="alertShow" id="3_1">
    </td><td class="alertShow" id="3_2"></td>
    <td class="alertShow" id="3_3"></td>
    <tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried `.attr("id")` (lowercase)?

Comment: yes,but no change in result

Comment: sorry guys i apologize for my mistake,the code i posted that is working properly i just checked in console in browser,the things you guys suggested that i was applying in my code and there it was not working  , might have  some other issues

Comment: You can delete your question then ;)

Comment: i don't think this is necessary this could be helpful to someone else

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 $('#example').on('click', '.alertShow', function () {
            var id=$(this).attr("id");
            alert(id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you have a typo in your code - replace `attr("Id")` with `attr("id")`

secondly, `$(this)` already refers to `td`, so there is no need in using `closest` - `$(this).attr("id")` is enough

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correct. Just change `attr("Id")` to `attr("id")`

Check this link-

https://jsfiddle.net/codecore/Lbq1x590/12/

Comment: i tried that as well,but still it shows table id only

Answer (score 0):

$(document).on("click", "#board td", function(e) { var data = $(this).attr('id'); alert (data); });

Comment: soory but this is also not working it shows table it in alert instead of Td id

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$('#example td.alertShow').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is the Working Code for what you are trying to achieve-

https://jsfiddle.net/d5mk4q77/2/


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table border="1"  id="example">
<tr>
<td class="alertShow" id="2_0">11</td>
<td class="alertShow" id="2_1">22</td>
<td class="alertShow" id="2_2">33</td>
<td class="alertShow" id="2_3">44</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="alertShow" id="3_0">55</td>
<td class="alertShow" id="3_1">66</td>
<td class="alertShow" id="3_2">77</td>
<td class="alertShow" id="3_3">88</td>
<tr>
</table>
</body>



$('#example').on('click', '.alertShow', function () {
            var id=$(this).closest('td').attr("Id");
            alert(id);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use JQuery you can do:

```
$("td").click(function(){
    alert(this.id)
})
```

If you don't use JQuery just add

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

To your `<head></head>` tags

You could also do (to only use the example table)

```
    $("#example tr td").click(function(){
        alert(this.id)
    })
```